# Count value if columns match

Tags: r, bash

I have two rows in a df like so:

```
chr1    4771959 4772759     1   AJAP1
chr1    4771959 4772759     3   AJAP1
chr1    6291961 6292179     1   ICMT
chr1    6291961 8421822     3   ICMT
```

I want to compare the first three columns and if identical then combine and add the values from the fourth column. My desired output would be this:

```
chr1    4771959 4772759     4   AJAP1
chr1    6291961 6292179     1   ICMT
chr1    6291961 8421822     3   ICMT
```

Is this possible in bash or alternatively, if easier, in R??

Comment: looking for some clarification ... 1) would I be correct in assuming that not only do columns #1-3 need to be the same but also column #5 (otherwise, could you provide an example of the desired output if column #5 is different?) ... 2) will the data always be compared 2 lines at a time, or could there be a situation where you have 1, 3, or more lines that need to be compared (and if so, which column designates which rows are associated ... just column #5?)

Comment: Hi markp, by default if the first three columns match then every other column (except column 4) will be identical. Column 4 is read counts for that gene so I want to sum this column if all others match (which they will if columns 1-3 match).

Answer (score 3):

In R, you could use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(V4~., df, sum)
#    V1      V2      V3    V5 V4
#1 chr1 4771959 4772759 AJAP1  4
#2 chr1 6291961 6292179  ICMT  1
#3 chr1 6291961 8421822  ICMT  3
```

DATA

```
df = structure(list(V1 = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1"), V2 = c(4771959L, 
4771959L, 6291961L, 6291961L), V3 = c(4772759L, 4772759L, 6292179L, 
8421822L), V4 = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), V5 = c("AJAP1", "AJAP1", "ICMT", 
"ICMT")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash you'd use awk:

```
$ awk '
{
    a[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3]+=$4
    b[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3]=$5
}
END {
    for(i in a)
        print i,a[i],b[i]
}' file
chr1 6291961 8421822 3 ICMT
chr1 6291961 6292179 1 ICMT
chr1 4771959 4772759 4 AJAP1
```

Comment: Thank you #James Brown. I had managed to get the first part but was stuck as this was printing out the same gene name. You have solved it with putting in b!

Answer (score 0):

In bash I would say:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A hash
declare -A sum

while read line; do
    set -- $line
    hash[$1,$2,$3]=$line
    sum[$1,$2,$3]=$((${sum[$1,$2,$3]} + $4))
done

for key in ${!hash[@]}; do
    set -- ${hash[$key]}
    echo -e "$1\t$2\t$3\t${sum[$1,$2,$3]}\t$5"
done
```